# Chrome Dev Tools Color Picker Contrast Ratio not showing up

Tags: google-chrome, colors, accessibility, google-chrome-devtools, contrast

According to the dev tools docs, you can [view the contrast ratio of a text element in the Color Picker](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/accessibility/reference#contrast) as of [Chrome 65 - January 2018](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#contrast)

However, sometimes the functionality appears buggy, as identified in this thread on [Is "Contrast ratio" no longer available in Developer Tools?](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/15827676?hl=en)

Here's an example where the contrast picker doesn't show up

[image: no contrast information available]

Sometimes adding a background color can trigger it into working again.  Has anyone else successfully found a way to get it to work?  Are the others tools / recommendations to fallback to if the native contrast toolbox doesn't show up?

**Alternative**: [contrast contrast in FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvCNJ.png)

Comment: It works only in some cases, for example if element has only text - it will work, but if element has text and links - it may not work.

Comment: Still an issue in March 2022, despite this training page from Google: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/devtools-cvd#3

Comment: When I check on production it's there, when on localhost in development mode, not there.

Answer (score 7):

You can check contrast in CSS Overview panel too. And some color combinations, which otherwise would have this "No contrast information available" label when checked with Inspect, do seem to appear there.

Comment: Where is the CSS Overview panel?

Comment: Click on the three dots button in the Dev tools, then More tools, then CSS overview.

Comment: Oh I see, it seems to be new and experimental, it must have appeared after at least Chrome 94.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google thread, there's a suggestion towards the bottom to press F1 and `Restore defaults and reload`.

As an alternative, there's a WCAG contract checker here https://contrastchecker.com/

Comment: `Restore defaults and reload` didn't work for me.